# Can we remove the smoothing translate with DoMove?

Tags: unity-game-engine, dotween

i got a problem when i want to use DoMove function with DOTween it move to the given point but slow at the end and i want to remove if is it possible.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Tween.SetEase(Ease)` to change the easing type:

```
transform.DOMove(position, overTime).SetEase(Ease.Linear);
```

You can also change the default easing type through `DOTween.defaultEaseType`.

```
DOTween.defaultEaseType = Ease.Linear;
```